# Angular map not looping before returning observable

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm retrieving http response and i need to extract the json body into array. I successfully retrieved, but main problem is looping through returned data in map. It is not looping before returning observable.

In server class, I'm getting the json response and notice the for loop, it jumps to `return res;` without looping. Also anything i print inside the `forLoop` won't work.

```
  getServers() {
    return this.http.get('https://udemy-ng-http-56bbb.firebaseio.com/data.json')
      .pipe(map
      (res => {
        servers1: any;
        servers1 = res;
        for (const server of servers1) {
          server.name = 'FETCH_' + server.name;
        }
        return res;
      }));
  }
```

In `onGet()`, I also tried to loop when i subscribe to it. Still not working

```
  onGet() {
    this.serverService.getServers().subscribe(
       (response) => {
         for (this.server of response) {
           this.server.name = 'FETCH_' + this.server.name;
           console.log( this.server.name.json());
         }
       },
       (error) => console.log(error)
    );
  }
```

I expected this `forloop` to work just like below without `pipe`. I'm using `RxJS 6+` with `..pip(map)..`. It worked when using `rxjs-compat` without pipe

```
  getServers() {
    return this.http.get('https://udemy-ng-http-56bbb.firebaseio.com/data.json').map
      (res => {
        this.servers1 = res;
        for (const server of this.servers1) {
          server.name = 'FETCH_' + server.name;
        }
        return res;
      });
  }
```

This is the output.

```
-LdlacC74PPS93h9HzQc: Array(2)
0:
capacity: 10
id: 1108
name: "Testserver"
__proto__: Object
1:
capacity: 100
id: 953
name: "Liveserver"
__proto__: Object
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
-LdnUvw_idV440wn3uIA: Array(2)
0:
capacity: 10
id: 6006
name: "Testserver"
__proto__: Object
1:
capacity: 100
id: 4260
name: "Liveserver"
__proto__: Object
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
```

The name should be `FETCH_ Testserver` not just `Testserver`.

Comment: any errors in the console

Comment: also missed the declaration of servers1. `let  servers1: any;`

Comment: Isn't your `res` empty then, tried logging it outside loop?

Comment: @Sachila I'm not getting error

Comment: @xyz Is not empty. I logged it

Comment: @KofoworolaSadique What is it? Please show the log of `res`.

Comment: I have updated with the output, it skipped the for loop

Comment: The name should be `FETCH_ Testserver` not just `Testserver`

Comment: @xyz are you there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below:

```
getServers() {
    return this.http.get('https://udemy-ng-http-56bbb.firebaseio.com/data.json')
      .pipe(map
      (res => this.transformationMethod(res)));
  }

transformationMethod(res){ 
  Object.keys(res.data).forEach(resKey => { 
     const obj = res.data[resKey]; 
     obj.forEach(data => { 
        data.name = 'Fetch_' + data.name; 
     }) 
   }) 
  return res; 
}
```

For data like:

```
data = {
    "data": {
      "-LdlacC74PPS93h9HzQc": [{
        "capacity": 10,
        "id": 1108,
        "name": "Testserver"
      }, {
        "capacity": 100,
        "id": 953,
        "name": "Liveserver"
      }],
      "-LdnUvw_idV440wn3uIA": [{
        "capacity": 10,
        "id": 6006,
        "name": "Testserver"
      }, {
        "capacity": 100,
        "id": 4260,
        "name": "Liveserver"
      }]
    }
  };
```

[A sample demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-httpclient-local-data-gvdfev?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Ok. I will get back to you.

Comment: @KofoworolaSadique : sure, i'll be waiting for your feedback

Comment: Unfortunately, the output still the same `-LdlacC74PPS93h9HzQc: Array(2)
0: {capacity: 10, id: 1108, name: "Testserver"}
1: {capacity: 100, id: 953, name: "Liveserver"}`

Comment: The name should be `FETCH_ Testserver` and   `FETCH_ Liveserver`

Comment: @KofoworolaSadique : What are `-LdlacC74PPS93h9HzQc: Array(2), ` ?? Share your json response in the question

Comment: `-LdlacC74PPS93h9HzQc: Array(2)` means the id has 2 data in it. See my updated question on json